# Multiple attributes in bison

Tags: compiler-construction, semantics, bison, lexical-analysis

I am doing semantic analysis in bison and i want to use multiple attribute associated with a token. A related part of my code is:

```
%union semrec
{
    int Type;
    char *id;

}

%start prog

%token <id>  tIDENT
```

Here, i can only use the "id" attribute witht the tIDENT token. I also want to associate the "Type" attribute with tIDENT token. To do this, i tried the following:

```
 %token <id>  tIDENT
 %token <Type>  tIDENT
```

But it gives me a redeclaration warning for token tIDENT. I also tried the following:

```
 %token <id> <Type> tIDENT
```

It also did not work. What can i do? I think this is just a little syntactic problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it this way: you have to define your `%union` in such a way that all the symbols that have multiple "attributes" have a `struct` to define all these "attributes".  Something like

```
%union
{
  struct
  {
    int type;
    char *id;
  } type_id;
}
%type <type_id> tIDENT
```

and use `$1.type` or `$1.id` etc.

Note however that I very much doubt that you're doing the right thing.  Chances are high that you will need an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).  You should look for information about that.

Comment: Thanks, but this time i get the following error: In the scanner, i have something like that: [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* {yylval.id = (char *) strdup(yytext);return tIDENT;}
Now it says ‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named ‘id’

Comment: You also have to adjust your scanner, something like `yylval.type_id.id = strdup(yytext)`.  And you should probably read thoroughly Bison's documentation about semantic values.

Comment: Now it is ok, when i changed it to [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* {yylval.type_id.id = (char *) strdup(yytext);return tIDENT;}. Thank you very much!